# The program freezes when i put a while loop in a action listener

Tags: java, swing

The program freezes because I put a loop in the action listener for the grandma button.I know why it won't work, but I can't seem to find a way around it. Can anyone tell me away around it.

I'm new to Java, and to practice I'm making a cookie clicker game. If you do not know what cookie clicker is, it is essentially a game where you click a button to get more cookies, and then use cookies to buy more items that automatically produce cookies. In this program, there is a cookie button that works, and a grandma button that should trigger a while loop, that will add a cookie every 5 seconds.

```java
public class conn extends JFrame {

public int cookies;
//public int cps;
public int grandmas;
public int pg;


 JButton ck;
 JButton bgrandma;

 //JTextArea cpslog;
 JTextArea Cookies;
 //JTextArea amount;

conn() {
    super("");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JFrame scree = new JFrame();

    pg = pg + 10;



    ck = new JButton("Cookie");
    add(ck, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            cookies++;
            Cookies.setText(null);
            Cookies.setEditable(false);
            Cookies.append( cookies + " Cookies");

        } 

    });


    Cookies = new JTextArea();
    add(Cookies, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);


    bgrandma = new JButton("Buy a Grandma(" + pg + ")");
    add(bgrandma, BorderLayout.WEST);
    bgrandma.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(cookies >= pg) {
            grandmas++;
            //cps++;
            //cps++;
            cookies = cookies-pg;
            Cookies.setText(null);
            Cookies.append(cookies + " Cookies");


        } 
            while(grandmas > 0) {
                cookies++;
                Cookies.setText(null);
                Cookies.append(cookies + " Cookies");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000 / grandmas);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }   
        });



    setVisible(true);
    setSize(600, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Cookie Clicker");

    }


}
```

Comment: Wild guess: You want a javax.swing.Timer to update your game as time goes by

Comment: I bet the issue is with the sleep within the loop. All the other times I've seen this issue it was an issue with wait/sleep/pause in loops.

Answer (score 3):

> In this program, there is a cookie button that works, and a grandma button that should trigger a while loop, that will add a cookie every 5 seconds.::

Don't use a loop in the ActionListener. The loop blocks the Event Dispatch Thread and prevents the GUI from repainting itself.

Instead you should be using a `Swing Timer`

Read the sections from the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) on:

1. `Concurrency in Swing`
2. `How to Use Timers`

for more information.

Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Sometimes your names are correct and sometimes they are not. Be consistent!!!

And get rid of all that blank space. Use proper formatting if you want to post code for people to read. Right now the posted code is a mess to read.

Comment: Why would you un-accept an answer 5 years later? That advice was good then and still applies now.