# GUI Program freezes once inside action performed method in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to redirect my system.out.println to dislpay to the JTextArea element of the GUI (hence it being public and static so that the methods that print something can print to it.

But once it gets to the line:

```
System.out.println("sdsdsdsdsa");
```

the program just does not go any further. The next two lines are:

```
System.setOut(printStream);
System.setErr(printStream);
```

which it does not seem to print out and when I exit the program this error appears:

"Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main""

and I am unable to verify whether printStream is null or not because the debugger does not seem to following into the action performed method once the start button (JButton1) is pressed.

Below is the main class in the GUI:

```
public class TrainingProgramme {

static PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new GUITextOutputStream(TrainingProgrammeGUI.jTextArea1));

 public static void main(String[] args) {

TrainingProgrammeGUI gui = new TrainingProgrammeGUI();
gui.setVisible(true);
System.setOut(printStream);
System.setErr(printStream);

System.out.println("==================================\n"+
                   "* WELCOME TO CATCH ME IF YOU CAN *\n"+
                   "==================================\n");

}
```

GUI class:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author viljo
 */

public class TrainingProgrammeGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

static PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new GUITextOutputStream(TrainingProgrammeGUI.jTextArea1));
double startTimer = System.nanoTime();
double stopTimer = 0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Player gameCharacter = null;
Teacher teacher = null;
int finishedProgram = 0;   
int userChoice = -1;  

/**
 * Creates new form TrainingProgrammeGUI
 */
public TrainingProgrammeGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

filler1 = new javax.swing.Box.Filler(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 32767));
jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
jLabel1.setText("CIA Training Programme");

jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
jTextArea1.setRows(5);
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
jLabel2.setText("Game: ");

jButton1.setText("Start Game");
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

jButton3.setText("What is this game?");
jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
jLabel3.setText("Type Here: ");

jButton4.setText("Exit");
jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addGap(159, 159, 159))
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(261, 261, 261)
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 456, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(170, 170, 170)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        .addContainerGap(175, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addContainerGap()
        .addComponent(jLabel1)
        .addGap(70, 70, 70)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 60, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jLabel3))
        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 226, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2))
        .addGap(20, 20, 20))
);

pack();
}// </editor-fold>



/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
     TrainingProgrammeGUI programme = new TrainingProgrammeGUI();
     programme.setVisible(true);
}

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    System.out.print("\nThank you for using our training programme!");
    System.exit(0);
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.out.println("sdsdsdsdsa");
    System.setOut(printStream);
    System.setErr(printStream);
System.out.println("==================================\n"+
                   "* WELCOME TO CATCH ME IF YOU CAN *\n"+
                   "==================================\n");                                     

userChoice = TrainingProgramme.checkInputWithPhrase("1.) Start Game\n2.) What is this game?\n3.) Quit", 1, 3);

teacher = new Teacher("John Doe", "Teacher");

gameCharacter = teacher.introductionLines(); // teacher reads a few lines and asks questions then returns Player class

boolean userFinished = false;
gameCharacter.getHotelRoom().setPlayerHere(true);
do {  // Checks which room player is in then reads instructions for room. Loop finishes when player wants to chooses suspect
    if (gameCharacter.getHotelKitchen().isPlayerHere()) {
    if ("HotelRoom".equals((gameCharacter.getHotelKitchen().instructions(teacher)))) {
        System.out.println("\nRoom chosen!\n");
        gameCharacter.getHotelKitchen().setPlayerHere(false); // Takes player out of current room
        gameCharacter.getHotelRoom().setPlayerHere(true);     // Puts players into chosen room
        }
    } else {
        if ("Choose".equals((gameCharacter.getHotelRoom().instructions(teacher)))) {    
            stopTimer = System.nanoTime();
            Player.timeTaken = (stopTimer - startTimer) / 10000000; //time taken to finish inspecting items (in seconds)
            teacher.chooseWhoDidIt(gameCharacter);
            finishedProgram = 1; //Stop the curret loop
            userFinished = true; //Stop the main menu loop
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nKitchen chosen!\n");
            gameCharacter.getHotelRoom().setPlayerHere(false);// Takes player out of current room
            gameCharacter.getHotelKitchen().setPlayerHere(true);// Puts players into chosen room
        }
    }
} while (userFinished == false);
}  



private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.out.println("\n+===========================================================+");
    System.out.println("|This game was created to help train our new junior recruits|");
    System.out.println("+===========================================================+\n\n");

    System.out.println("Objective: Gather evidence by looking for clues\n"+ 
                       "and once you are done go back to the room to guess \n"+
                       "which suspect did it. Suspects are provided once you have\n"+ 
                       "went back to the room and decided to guess who did the crime!\n");
}                                        

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.Box.Filler filler1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
public static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

PrintStream class:

```
package net.codejava.swing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 * This class extends from OutputStream to redirect output to a JTextArrea
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // redirects data to the text area
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char)b));
        // scrolls the text area to the end of data
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your do-while loop is blocking the Swing event thread, rendering the GUI frozen and useless. Get rid of the loop, that's not how you want to create event-driven programs.

Comment: You have an infinite loop in your ActionListener. Therefore the GUI can't repaint itself until the loop finishes. The ActionListener should only be used to start a Swing Timer. The Swing Timer will then schedule the animation. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information. Also read the section from the table of contents on `Concurrency in Swing` to understand why you can't have an infinite loop in the ActionListener.

Comment: Please check out @camickr's answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524522/the-program-freezes-when-i-put-a-while-loop-in-a-action-listener)

Comment: You can also check out [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for reusable code that allows you to redirect output.

Comment: But you probably don't need a Swing Timer, but rather will want to look up and create a state-machine type of game where your GUI's response to input will depend on its current "state", the values held by key state fields.

Comment: I really apreciate everyones help here! I am going to read the suggested questions and sections and make some changes then get back to you once I have done so.

Comment: So I have fixed my main class for the GUI to have no loops to keep the program, as you said, event driven. However, a lot of my methods have loops in them and I assume that is why the program is still freezing. 

My question is, how am I supposed to not use loops for doing things like verifying a users input and then asking the same phrase as I currently ask the question and if its incorrect answer I ask them again.  I looked at Swing Timers but that does not seem to be used in place of loops. "When you create the timer, you specify an action listener to be notified when the timer "goes off"

Comment: Alright, I just removed all do while loops from my program and I am still having the same issue. It still freezes/does nothign when I press the buttons.